# Socket or Firebase, Which is the best approach for chat application in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Which is the best approach for chat application in Flutter? Socket or Firebase?

I'm developing an app using Flutter. Chat is one of the add-on features in my app. I'm using Node as a backend service. And I'm using Firebase also to handle my notifications.

I would like to know which is the best approach to implement the chat in my application.

Comment: There is also the stream_chat_flutter package if you haven't considered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase is easier to use but with socket you have more control. Firebase can become a bit expensive. So it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have want to develop such chat functionality as fast as possible,Firebase is the better option as it has realtime database and as well as APIs already there but it has some pricing on terms of the usage. If you have a longer time to develop such chat functionality  and have worked with socket before then you can go for socket.